# Spawning multiple coin node(s) using an array Swift SpriteKit

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody

I use a function (shown below) to spawn a coin node in specific locations at random using an array.

Using this function, I am trying to incorporate more than one coin node (that are slightly different from one another) into this function so that multiple nodes can use this array to spawn and function just like the first coin node.

The problem that I have is that when I incorporate another node into this function or make a new but similar function for the 2nd node I get a Thread 1 SIGABERT error after the game crashes.

I currently have two separate functions for each node that are very similar, but with slight differences to accommodate each node.

```
 func generateCoinZero() {

    if(self.actionForKey("spawningCoinZero") != nil){return}
    let coinTimerZero = SKAction.waitForDuration(2, withRange: 7)

    let spawnCoinZero = SKAction.runBlock {
    let coinZeroTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "coinZero")

    self.coinZero = SKSpriteNode(texture: coinZeroTexture)
    self.coinZero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.coinZero.size.height / 12)
    self.coinZero.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.coinZero.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.coinZero.zPosition = 1

    self.coinZero.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.coinZeroCategory
    self.coinZero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.playerCategory
    self.coinZero.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    self.player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.playerCategory
    self.player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    self.player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.boundary

    var coinPositionZero = Array<CGPoint>()
    coinPositionZero.append((CGPoint(x:250, y:139)))
    coinPositionZero.append((CGPoint(x:790, y:298)))
    coinPositionZero.append((CGPoint(x:225, y:208)))
    coinPositionZero.append((CGPoint(x:220, y:237)))

    let spawnLocationZero = coinPositionZero[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(coinPositionZero.count)))]
    let actionZero = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveToX(+self.xScale, duration: 2.0))

    self.coinZero.runAction(actionZero)
    self.coinZero.position = spawnLocationZero
    self.addChild(self.coinZero)
    print(spawnLocationZero)
    }

  let sequenceZero = SKAction.sequence([coinTimerZero, spawnCoinZero])
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequenceZero), withKey: "spawningCoinZero") 
}

func generateCoinTwo() {

    if(self.actionForKey("spawnCoinTwo") != nil){return}
    let coinTimerTwo = SKAction.waitForDuration(2, withRange: 7)

    let spawnCoinTwo = SKAction.runBlock {

        let coinTwoTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "coinTwo")
        self.coinTwo = SKSpriteNode(texture: coinTwoTexture)
        self.coinTwo.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.coinTwo.size.height / 12)
        self.coinTwo.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.coinTwo.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.coinTwo.zPosition = 1
        self.addChild(self.coinTwo)

        var coinPositionTwo = Array<CGPoint>()
        coinPositionTwo.append((CGPoint(x:250, y:139)))
        coinPositionTwo.append((CGPoint(x:790, y:298)))
        coinPositionTwo.append((CGPoint(x:225, y:208)))
        coinPositionTwo.append((CGPoint(x:220, y:237)))

        let spawnLocationTwo = coinPositionTwo[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(coinPositionTwo.count)))]
         let actionTwo = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveToX(+self.xScale, duration: 2.0))

        self.coinTwo.runAction(actionTwo)
        self.coinTwo.position = spawnLocationTwo
        self.addChild(self.coinTwo)
        print(spawnLocationTwo)
    }

    let sequenceTwo = SKAction.sequence([coinTimerTwo, spawnCoinTwo])
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequenceTwo), withKey: "spawnCoinTwo")
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am seeing this a lot... Why do you keep reference to the last spawned coin ? Also using self inside of a closure like that in combination with SKAction.repeatForever will create strong ref cycle ... Which line crashes ?

Comment: In your spawnCoinTwo SKAction block, you create 2 immutable variables - coinTwoTexture  and spawnLocationTwo. when this action runs for the second time, these will fail as the variables already exist. Try changing these to 'var' and moving them outside of the spawnCoinTwo SKAction block.

Comment: Can you post the exact failure messages?

Comment: To be frank this is kind of a mess. What do you want to happen exactly? Spawn n number of coins one at a time? Or n number of coins simultaneously?

Comment: @Whirlwind, Xcode doesn't seem to tell me which line is causing the issue, as the game plays for a few seconds then crashes and gives me the error message shown in the original question.

Comment: @SteveIves I have updated my original post with a screenshot of the error message right after the game crashes.

Comment: @T.BenjaminLarsen, I have two different coin nodes where the goal is to have these two coin nodes spawn using the same coordinates given in the array. I would like them to spawn one at a time. So for example let's say the first two coin's spawned are coinZero, then the next is coinTwo, after that is coinZero, and so on. Once I can achieve that result, then I will move on to adding in the collision properties for coinTwo.

Comment: Also @SteveIves would the two immutable variables created in the function 'generateCoinZero' also be contributing to the problem or is it only the two variables in 'generateCoinTwo'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, there are quite a lot of issues here, the main ones being the extreme duplication of code and having your `generateCoin...`-functions doing way too much. So here goes:

You state in the comments that the scene should have *two* coins spawning at different times at one of four possible positions. If the scene has *two* coins, then the scene has *two* coins. Let's just create these as properties and be done with it:

```
// Your two coin properties 
let coin1 = coinNode()
let coin2 = coinNode()

// the function from which they are created
func coinNode() -> SKSpriteNode {
    let coinNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coinZero")
    coinNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: coinNode.size.height / 2)
    coinNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    coinNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    coinNode.zPosition = 1

    coinNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.coinZeroCategory
    coinNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.playerCategory
    coinNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 // A ColliderType.none would be lovely...

    return coinNode
}
```

Now, these coins are not yet added to the scene nor do they have a proper position, this sounds like a fitting scope for another function:

```
func addCoin() {
    let positions = [ CGPoint(x:250, y:139), CGPoint(x:790, y:298), CGPoint(x:225, y:208), CGPoint(x:220, y:237)]
    let position = positions[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(positions.count)))]

    if coin1.parent == nil {
        coin1.position = position
        addChild(coin1)
    } else if coin2.parent == nil {
        coin2.position = position
        addChild(coin2)
    }
}
```

Finally you want to have this function being called so do the following in your scene's init or setup:

```
let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(1) // or however long you want it to be between each spawn
let addCoinCall = SKAction.runBlock({ self.addCoin() })
let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([delay, addCoinCall])
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnSequence))
```

Comment: Problem Solved, I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Just be careful when using self like this. Because the action is repeated it is queued for the next frame, and because the block strongly captures self, this may create strong reference cycle for example when transitioning to another scene. You can solve this in two ways. Use weak/unowned self inside of a capture list, or remove this action before transitioning.

Comment: @Whirlwind good point, I've personally made a habit of calling `removeAllActions` on any node I'm getting rid of.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `addChild twice`, put addChild out of `runBlock`, and make sure that you are addChild once.

If you want put multiple coin, is better to copy your node and add on the scene. 
You can create a node like coinZero out of function, and then inside the function do something like:

```
let coinToAdd = coinZero.copy()
```

Comment: coin has physicsbody, I do not think `copy` copies this, and I do not think it copies any children that may be added to coin

Comment: Sure, that copy also the physic proprieties, I do this

Comment: cool, they must have fixed that then because it didn't always

Comment: :) please try it, may be I have a good bug! :) I copy a custom class of SKNode inside .sks file. May be works only in this way?

Comment: Hi Simone, I am still learning swift and I just had one question for you regarding your answer. I just wanted to verify what you said so that I can be sure that I understand it. I will eliminate the ' generateCoinTwo ' function and use ' let coinTwo = coinZero.copy() '   inside of the ' generateCoinZero ' function?